# Optional Relational Filters

Tags: database-design

Let's say I have the following design:

Tables:

`video_games`
A list of all known video games

`video_game_modes`
A list of game modes for each video game.
For example:

- Game = League of Legends
- Game Mode = Ranked

`another_table`

What is the cleanest design for if `another_table` can reference both a `video_game` and a `video_game_mode` but `video_game_mode` is optional?

I could easily understand if all `video_games` had at least 1 blank `video_game_mode` as you would just reference that in `another_table`.

Comment: What exactly are the relationships between `"another_table"` and the 2 tables?

Comment: @ypercube The relationship is many games modes to one game, and another_table has one game mode. I know it can easily be done with a default game mode being added to each, I was just curious to know if there was a cleaner way?

Answer (score 0):

You can reference both in your new table (another_table) and have a foreign key to both video_games and video_game_modes.  Just make the column that references video_game_mode nullable.  You can then put a constraint to force unique against video_game and video_game_mode if your intent is to have one row per video game and mode combination.

If it's one-to-many from video_games to video_game_modes, you could add a constraint that both game and game_mode could not be populated simultaneously (enforce that one or the other is null).  Then if the game does not have any game modes, you can still reference the game directly, and foreign keys could be used to protect data integrity.

Comment: The relationship is many games modes to one game. I know it can easily be done with a default game mode being added to each, I was just curious to know if there was a cleaner way?